# How to type a polymorphic component that removes react.children based on prop types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How could i express in typescript that if an element is a self closing tag like the following:

Ex: `<img/>`

remove the children and make it a self closing component like

`<Component/>`

Here is what i have so far, im still trying to think through it.

I'm not concerned about the errors, im trying to find a way to type it correctly.

**PolyComponent.tsx**

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';

type Components = 'img' | 'div';

type SelfClosingTags<T> = T extends 'img' ? never : T; // <- this should have some logic to make the Component take children or it will be self closing. 

interface IMemoizedComponent<T> {
  as: SelfClosingTags<T>;
  children: ReactNode;
}


export default function MemoizedComponent<T extends Components>({
  as,
  children,
}: IMemoizedComponent<T>) {
  const Component = as || 'div';
  const MemoizedComp = React.memo(Component);

  // how to express that if Component is not a self closing tag like img, 
  // make it a wrapper component based on the generic. 

  if (Component as T) {  
    return <MemoizedComp>{children}</MemoizedComp>;
  } else {
    return <MemoizedComp />;
  }
}
```

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import MemoizedComponent from './components/PolyComponent';
export const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="p-2">
      <h1>React TSX Starter</h1>
      <MemoizedComponent as="img">test</MemoizedComponent>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-starter-typescript-rwwihh?file=App.tsx

Comment: Is the problem in your function, rendering it correctly, or is the problem occurring when you try to use it? And what is the problem? Unexpected behavior? What's the intended behavior? Errors in the console?

Comment: There is an error, but i don't care about that i can resolve that, im trying to find a way to type it properly in typescript.

Comment: Um yeah... that's what I'm asking. *Where* is the error...?

Comment: I mean does the logic look right to you ? cause i doubt it does, thats where i want the clarification on if possible :) I edited the post.

Comment: I would do it like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-starter-typescript-wz96uo?file=components/PolyComponent.tsx). Your condition `Component as SelfClosingTags<T>` doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: Thanks soooooo muchhhh, could you make this an answer so i could give you credit. this is helpful.

Comment: I'm going to hit the hay for now, but I will post an answer with a more detailed explanation tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition `Component as SelfClosingTags<T>` doesn't actually do anything since types are "erased at runtime", which means you're just checking if `Component` is truthy. You'll need to replace this with a runtime check like `===` or using an array with `includes`.

The prop types also should change based on the given component, so now it looks like this:

```
type SelfClosingTags<T> = T extends 'img' ? true : false;

type IMemoizedComponent<T extends Components> = {
  as: T;
} & (SelfClosingTags<T> extends true
  ? { children?: never }
  : { children?: ReactElement | ReactNode });
```

Previously, `as` was always `never` since you were effectively giving `SelfClosingTags` the type `string`.

[Codesandbox with changes (same as comment)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-starter-typescript-wz96uo?file=components/PolyComponent.tsx)